# How to interprete results from Poisson random coefficients analysis?

Tags: r, regression

I have obtained the following results in R from a random coefficient Poisson analysis.

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson ( log )
Formula: frequency ~ 1 + insgen + ageveh + make + area + (1 | ID) 
   Data: Panel

```
  AIC       BIC    logLik   deviance
```

1099.9670 1134.9262  -541.9835  1083.9670

Random effects:

Groups Name          Variance   Std.Dev.

ID  (Intercept)     1.551e-11     3.939e-06

Number of obs: 584, groups: ID, 584

Fixed effects:

```
          Estimate    Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)
```

(Intercept)    -22.98292   8432.07738    -0.003     0.9978

insgenM          0.02616     0.08806      0.297     0.7664

ageveho          0.05889     0.08586      0.686     0.4928

make             -0.10447    0.04126     -2.532    0.0113 *

area1             23.68571  8432.07738   0.003    0.9978

area2             23.85969  8432.07738   0.003    0.9977

area3             23.77374  8432.07738   0.003   0.9978

---

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘***’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:

```
    (Intr)  insgnM  ageveh  make    area1   area2
```

insgenM   0.000

ageveho   0.000  -0.037

make      0.000   0.071 0.108

area1    -1.000   0.000 0.000  0.000

area2    -1.000  0.000 0.000  0.000  1.000

area3   -1.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000  1.000

I have included predictors:gender (Male,female), area which has 4 levels (area 1,2,3,4) and vehicle age (New and old) and make of car.

Comment: You have included random effects for ID which is unnecessary because every data point has a unique ID (i.e., get rid of '(1|ID)' term). Run as just fixed effects and also try running without area as a covariate and compare AIC/BIC of models. Also I'm not sure you are incorporating make correctly, you probably want to use it as a factor variable but it is treating it as continuous. That could just be me reading it wrong though.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you want to post results of the two fixed effects analyses? I'd be grateful if you upvoted my comment if not.